# Parameter is not passing to controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Let's take an example.

https://www.example.net/xyz?page=2

Route File

```
Route::get('/xyz', 'controller@getpages');
```

Controller

```
public function getpages(Request $request) {
 dd($request->all());
}
```

Showing result as

```
array:1 [▼
 "/xyz" => null
]
```

instead of

```
 array:1 [▼
  "page" => "2"
  ]
```

Comment: Everything looks in order, are you 100% sure you are clicking the xyz?page=2 and not a regular /xyz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was in .htaccess file, so i retrieve the old .htaccess and putted it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public function getpages(Request $request) {
 print_r($request->page);
}
```

Also make sure you use : `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 0):

try

```php
$query = $request->query();

$page = $request->query('page');
```

In your code there is a mistake. you missed $ symbol

```
public function getpages(Request $request) {
 dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: He can just $request->page no need to use querry() in laravel latest versions to access querry parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

public function getpages(Request $request) {
  $request = $request->only('page');
  dd($request);
}
```

> There is no array. just only one parameter "$page"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

This is user register controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

public function register(Request $request){

        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data['password'] = app('hash')->make($data['password']);

        User::create($data);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);

     }
```